# Is it possible to convert three row in section details of a crystal report to three column

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Is it possible to convert three row of section details in crystal report to three column?

Comment: Post some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, Yes it is possible. There are 2 ways:

1) Using CrossTabs.

2) At data level using SQL Pivot.

1) Using Crosstabs: 
http://reportsyouneed.com/understanding-crystal-cross-tabs-part-1/

[Cross tab 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493334/Custom-sorting-for-Crystal-Report-Cross-Tab)

[Cross tab 3](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports/blog/2014/10/31/crystal-reports-crosstab)

2) Using SQL Pivot:

[Pivot 1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Pivot 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query)

[Almost what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

There are may other resources.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thats great. If you havent used my suggestion and found a way yourself, would be gret if you could post your new answer for others. Or else just mark my answer as the correct answer.